# How to stop my Custom Keyboard from 'floating' or being undocked on iPad

Tags: ipad, keyboard, uitextfield, inputview

I have a custom Keyboard that gets displayed for a certain UITextField when I set the textField's inputView to my KeyboardView. The keyboard works fantastically well but it has become apparent that the keyboard will 'float' if the user has previously undocked the built in Apple Keyboard or indeed split it.

I have searched for many hours for a way to ensure my custom keyboard does not act like this and instead stays docked to the bottom of the screen regardless as to whether the user has previously undocked the built in Apple Keyboard.

```
self.keyboardInputView = [[[KeyboardInputViewController_iPad alloc]
                            initWithNibName:@"KeyboardInputViewController_iPad"
                            bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] autorelease];
self.keyboardInputView.delegate = self;                
self.keyboardInputView.keyboardTextField = myTextField;
myTextField.inputView = self.keyboardInputView.view;
[myTextField becomeFirstResponder];
```

Comment: I am aware that this issue can be resolved by the user going into Settings>General>Keyboard and switching off Split Keyboard on the iPads, but I would like to dock my own Keyboard to the bottom of the screen regardless of their settings.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this issue? Please share!

Comment: Apologies for the delayed reply @Mayosse - Unfortunately I have still not found a solution, though I confess I gave up hope a while back. Luckily most iOS users are unaware of the Split Keyboard functionality.

Comment: ~10 years later... is there a good solution? :)

Answer (score 0):

### You shouldn't do this, neither is there a way to do so.

You cannot override user settings with a custom keyboard, especially not the ones that can improve the accessiblity of a user interface.

You *could* include a warning in the tutorial that your keyboard works best  while being locked to the bottom, but you must ask yourself the question whether this is good UX or not. I would say the latter.