# How to stop iOS Custom InputView from floating around the screen

Tags: ios, inputview

I came across a problem exactly as mentioned in the question in the link below.

[How to stop my Custom Keyboard from 'floating' or being undocked on iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12837275/how-to-stop-my-custom-keyboard-from-floating-or-being-undocked-on-ipad)

Does anyone have a solution for fixing this.

Thanks in advance.